# JSON KeyError on Wayback Machine scraper

Tags: python, json, beautifulsoup

I'm building a simple program to get all page title from a list of URLs, then write them to a CSV file. I've done and understood most parts, except one thing : I keep getting Key Error over and over no matter how I changed the code. Please take a look and tell me what's wrong with these codes :

```
import requests
import json
import urllib2
import csv
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup

def getsnapshot(domain):
    base = 'http://archive.org/wayback/available?url='
    r = requests.get(base+domain, verify=False)
    j = json.loads(r.text)
    if j['archived_snapshots'] == {}:
        pass
    else:
        archive_url = j['archived_snapshots']['closest']['url']
    return archive_url

def gettitle(url):
    soup = BeautifulSoup(urllib2.urlopen(getsnapshot(url)))
    return soup.title.string

def writecsv(domain):
    c = csv.writer(open("output.csv", "wb"))
    snapshoturl = getsnapshot(domain)
    title = gettitle(snapshoturl)
    c.writerow([domain,title])

with open('input.txt', 'r') as f:
    for line in f.read().splitlines():
        writecsv(line)
```

My input is simply a list of URL, specifically domain names. I was checking domain history to see if there was spamming in the past.

Here's the JSON

```
{
  "archived_snapshots": {
    "closest": {
      "available": true,
      "url": "http://web.archive.org/web/20050408030822/http://www.001music.net:80/",
      "timestamp": "20050408030822",
      "status": "200"
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think your issue is that you assume that if `j['archive_snapshots']` is non-empty, it will always contain a key mapping 'closest' to a dictionary containing key 'url'.  Validate this assumption and you should be good do go:

```
if 'archived_snapshots' in j and j['archived_snapshots']:
    return j['archived_snapshots'].get('closest',{}).get('url')
```

This will return `None` if any of those assumptions were `False`, so adjust the callers of `getsnapshot()` accordingly to only proceed when the url `is not None` (Alternately, raise an exception and wrap calls in a `try/except` block)

Also, your current code will overwrite the file every new row you add.  Either open in append mode (`open("output.csv", "a")`) or more efficiently, wrap your for loop in an additional `with` call and pass in the `csv.writer()` object directly to `writecsv()`

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using `r.json()`? which is built in to the `requests` lib
KeyError often relates to what you do with the object or dict, but you haven't shown us the json.

Also, `requests` can substitue `urllib2`. I'd try using `requests` only

Comment: Hi, thanks for the recommendation. I've updated the question with json included. Can you please take a look again?

Comment: which line are you getting the error from? and the error message?

Comment: actually the conditional statement from `getsnapshot(domain)` doesn't seem to return the correct URL. If I changed it to
`archive_url = j['archived_snapshots']['closest']['url'] if not j['archived_snapshots'] else ''`

it yields `KeyError : 'closest'`

Comment: so you are trying to access `closest` when there is no such key. Review your return values and adjust accordingly